# How does this iteration work: for(++s ; *s; ++s)

Tags: c, string, for-loop

Given a string pointer `s` in C, what does the following iteration do? i.e in what manner does it iterate over the string?

```
for (++s ; *s; ++s);
```

Comment: Starting from `str[1]` instead of `str[0]`

Comment: And until the null character. And by modifying the `s` pointer, so it won't be very useful afterwards.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is the null character still "presented" to the body of the iteration on its last loop, does the iteration stop on the character before the null character?

Comment: @ARF The loop won't process the null character.

Comment: How come you are "stumped" by `++s` in the first argument, but not stumped by it in the last argument. What's the difference?

Comment: What happens when the loop is entered and where such a loop stops etc can easily be inspected with a debugger.

Comment: That loop will give really bad behavior if s points to a typical empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct

```
for (init ; cond ; incr) { body }
```

roughly translates to (left in pseudo-code)

```
init
while cond:
    body
    incr
```

Thus the original can be viewed as the following, in which case the semantics should be easier to follow:

```
++s;
while (*s) {
   /* no body shown */
   ++s;
}
```

Comment: Wait, _not an answer_? What is it doing here, then?

Comment: @ForceBru Well, "not an answer" as in - I'm not going to fill in any more details, eg. what the `++` does or expand on "roughly". If comments could be so long I'd have left it there. In any case, I uhh, "tidied" the opening.

Answer (score 4):

`for (++s ; *s; ++s)` means that

1. Increment pointer `s` to second element of string, i.e, `s[1]`.
2. Check whether `*s` is `\0` or not.
3. If `*s != 0`, then execute the loop body else go to step 5.
4. Increment `s` by `1`. Go to step 3.
5. Exit loop.

Answer (score 3):

It just starts iterating from `str[1]` instead of `str[0]` checking if `*str` is a null-terminator.

This works like this: let `str` be array of 5 characters.
str->['f']['k']['g']['h']['\0']

`++str` is 'k' while `str[0]` is 'f'. Then it loops until '\0' is found.

Answer (score 1):

This for statement

```
for (++s ; *s; ++s)
```

in fact is equivalent to the following

```
for ( int i = 1; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i )
```

The only difference is that after the first for statement pointer s will be moved along the string while in the second for statamenet it is the index (variable i) that will be changed in iterations.